# Selenium 3.7 webdriver Error: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium3

Upgraded to Selenium 3.7 recently and ran into error.

Error trace log:

> Debug 1
>   Debug 2
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2) on port 2198
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   System info: host: 'Maggies-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>       at AutomationFrameWork.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:13)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:2198/status] to be available after 20005 ms
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>       ... 10 more

Code:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Debug 1");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/maggie/Documents/ToolsQA/Libs/chromedriver"); 
    System.out.println("Debug 2");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.out.println("Debug 3");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Included Libraries:
selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar

System Environment:

> Mac OS: '10.12.6'
>
> java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>
> selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar
>
> geckodriver - v0.19.1
>
> ChromeDriver 2.33
>
> Chrome Version 62.0.3202.89 (64-bit)

Thank you for any thought.

Comment: In most such cases your specific **driver version** doesn't work with the specific **browser version**. Try different versions of both, also read what the devs say about support. It could also get more complicated for different systems like your **Mac**. On my **Raspberry Pi** for example I searched nearly 2 hours for driver-browser version pair that worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, on Mac OS. Check your /etc/hosts file and make sure you have 127.0.0.1 binding to localhost. I was missing that, added it and voila!

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing `WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.` try the below mentioned steps :

- Uninstall Google Chrome through `Revo Uninstaller`.
- Install the latest version of `Google Chrome`.
- Perform some steps on the website so you are sure that the website opens properly.
- If needed induce `Explicit Wait` i.e. `WebDriverWait`

Comment: I tried with firefox and geckodriver but still running into "Connection refused" error. I don't think it is because of browser issue.

Comment: @Maggie What's your ChromeDriver & Geckodriver version, can you update the Question with the version info please?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/maggie/Documents/ToolsQA/Libs/chromedriver" to "/Users/maggie/Documents/ToolsQA/Libs/chromedriver.exe" and try this

Comment: Read the question - the OP is on a mac!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6, chrome browser 74 and selenium-java-3.141.59
Changed the selenium java libs to version selenium-java-3.13.0 it worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues. Problem was with my ChromeDriver, I downloaded latest stable version and it worked.

Link for ChromeDriver : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/